# remove default splash screen android & ios flutter

Tags: flutter

i preferred use custom splash screen that's allow me to build whole page . so , am trying to remove default splash from android and ios

```
void main() async {
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);

  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Navigation Basics',
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: new SplashPage(),
    routes: {
      // When navigating to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen widget.
      '/home': (BuildContext context) => new FirstRoute(),
    },
  ));
}

class SplashPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SplashPageState createState() => SplashPageState();
}

class SplashPageState extends State<SplashPage> {

  void navigationToNextPage() {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
  }

  startSplashScreenTimer() async {
    var _duration = new Duration(seconds: 5);
    return new Timer(_duration, navigationToNextPage);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startSplashScreenTimer();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);

    return Container(
        child: new Image.asset('images/banner.png', fit: BoxFit.fill));
  }
}
```

so i need to  remove default splash screen from both with flutter

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The default splash screen cannot be overridden with Dart/Flutter alone. They are controls shown by the native Android/iOS context while the Flutter runtime is initializing. As such, any splash screen widget you create inside Flutter will show *after* the default splash screen. (Even if you completely remove the default splash image, the app would just be a blank while screen until Flutter finished loading, and that's bad design.)

There are instructions on how to change the default splash screen [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-2019-real-splash-screens-tutorial-16078660c7a1). If you are well-versed in native Android or iOS development, you could take it a step further than just a simple image if you wanted.

Comment: Thanks , then how to add image full fixed height and width 100% for ios and android

Comment: @MikelTawfik I don't recall off the top of my head, but the splash screen is a pretty simplistic Android control and iOS storyboard, so it should be pretty easy to find via Google. That said, I don't recommend having your splash screen fill the screen 100% as phone screens come in all shapes and sizes, so an image that looks fine on one phone will look stretched and distorted on another.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by ignoring adding a launcher icon.

In android go to app -> main -> res -> drawable -> launch_background.xml and leave it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />    
    <!-- <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </item> -->
</layer-list>
```

Comment: how about in iOS @Ashnet

Comment: i havent try it on iOS but maybe it's the same! if you try it please notifi us

Comment: I have tried this but its still showing the default splash screen image which is the app main icon, is there a better solution now?

Comment: That's how it is currently and there is the flutter splash screen on boot. I don't think changing nothing is a good solution.