# How to remove default launch screen?

Tags: flutter

I want to make an animated splash screen.I use animated_splash_screen package for doing it.However,before this splash screen app shows default launch screen.How can I remove default launch screen?So I want to show users only new generated splash screen.
[image: it is opened firstly]
[image: then new generated splash is showed]

I tried to change some codes from AndroidManifest but it did not help.
What can I do alternatively?

Comment: you can see the solution here:
[remove default splash screen android & ios flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57895435/remove-default-splash-screen-android-ios-flutter)

Comment: This question is already answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73146269/how-to-remove-flutters-default-splash-screen)