# How can I hide the default splash screen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I launch the app, I think I see a splash screen with the Flutter icon in the center of the screen.
How can I hide this?
Please let me know if you can help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove default splash screen android & ios flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57895435/remove-default-splash-screen-android-ios-flutter)

Comment: No, it has not been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it blank image or image of your choice using this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash

As in answer mentioned by David Gomes you can comment out image in  (which is already in flutter project by default now)

```
android\app\src\main\res\drawable\launch_background.xml
```

.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
<!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
<!-- <item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/launch_image" />
</item> -->
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I found out how to hide the splash screen on Android by commenting it out, but do you know how to hide it on iOS?

Comment: If you haven't found any answer for iOS use the package mentioned above and use blank transparent png image as splash-screen. I don't have mac so i cant test it. Package do support iOS so think you should try it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the styles.xml files.

```
 <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```